# Stored procedure returned (out) null

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic

I try to get return value of this Oracle stored procedure with VBScript, but everytime returned `NULL` (nothing), not populate `cmd("retVal")`. Where is my mistake?

If this stored procedure works fine it must return a integer value like 1 or -2 parameters are passed and change db data, but not return any value in OUT param in stored procedure.

```vb
Set connORA = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connORA.ConnectionString = "conninfo"
connORA.Open

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = connORA

cmd.CommandText = "{call procedureName(486954,100002335,'0','0',0,'12-03-2015','X','IPTAL_EDILDI',443,'SAT',?)}"
cmd.Prepared = True
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("retVal", 131, 2)
cmd.Execute

Response.Write cmd("retVal")

Set oCmd = Nothing
connORA.Close
Set connORA=nothing
```

Comment: What happens if you call the procedure with those exact params directly in SQL*Plus (or other tool of your choice)? Also, what's the spec of the stored proc? (Including datatypes)

Comment: Boneist, When i call directly with toad (like sql plus tool) it give me error for last question mark ": invalid character" last question mark for out param it must be populate stored procedure completes.

Comment: You'd need to declare a variable to hold your output parameter value, then you'd have to use something like dbms_output.put_line to display the value (make sure the dbms_output tab is turned on, if it's not already set to automatically fetch after procedure completion). See [here for an example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm#sthref1713)